Match Values in Comma Separated string
I need to match my input within column which is comma separated and get equivalent value



col 1
col2




X
AB 1.0,CD 1.0,CD 2.0


Y
AE 2.0,CD 3.0



If I pass Input as CD 1.0  I need to check in this table and it should return X if I pass CD 2.0 then it should give result X If input is CD 3.0 then result should be Y

This is a very bad data model. You should change it, so that each entry ('AB 1.0', 'CD 1.0', etc.) gets its own row. Then, you tagged the request with plsql. Do you really want a solution in Oracle's programming language PL/SQL? You don't say so in your request. Then, you tagged the request with plsqldeveloper. So, you are using the tool PL/SQL Developer by allround automations? And you expect that the solution will be dependent on the tool you are using to query the database? That is unlikely. And why the plsql-package tag? Your question is not about how packages work in PL/SQL.

I suppose that you want to tag your request with oracle, because it seems you are working with an Oracle database and want a solution for this system, and with sql, because you are probably looking for a SQL solution. Please correct the tags. But as mentioned: It is the database you should fix rather than looking for a workaround query.

Given the existing data model, here are a couple of slightly fragile approaches:
-- T is a dummy table for demonstration
with T as (
select 'X' as col1,     'AB 1.0,CD 1.0,CD 2.0' as col2 from dual
union
select 'Y' as col1,     'AE 2.0,CD 3.0' as col2 from dual
)
select col1 from T where ','||col2||',' like '%,'||'CD 1.0'||',%'
/

In this example, we add delimiters to both sides of the list column and use a like clause. This has a couple of issues:

We are depending on the search text not containing the delimiter
We need to apply a function to col2, and the LIKE clause contains a leading wildcard, preventing us from using indexes.

with T as (
select 'X' as col1,     'AB 1.0,CD 1.0,CD 2.0' as col2 from dual
union
select 'Y' as col1,     'AE 2.0,CD 3.0' as col2 from dual
)
select col1 from T where regexp_like(col2, '^(.*,)?'||'CD 3.0' || '(,.*)?$')
/

This one is a little bit more formal in that it uses a regular expression.

The function still needs to be applied to all rows being evaluated.
This would have issues with search text that breaks regular expression syntax.
The regular expression will be more flexible than the LIKE approach

As others have mentioned, the table design is not optimal; nevertheless, there are times when we have to work with a an existing production database that cannot be changed, possibly provided by a vendor. We do the best we can to work with what we have.
In both cases, the search text should be groomed so that it does not have embedded delimiters (e.g. '%' or ',') and possibly to remove leading and trailing whitespace.

You can tokenize the target string with classical regexp_substr and connect by or with XPATH expression, you have the choice to put the condition in the XPATH or in the outer WHERE clause:
select col1, val
from 
data d,
xmltable( 
  'for $i in (ora:tokenize($X,",")) return $i'
  passing col2 as "X"
  
  columns 
    val varchar2(4000) path '.'
) tb
where val = 'CD 3.0'
;

select col1, val
from 
data d,
xmltable( 
  'for $i in (ora:tokenize($X,",")) where ($target = $i) return $i'
  passing col2 as "X", 'CD 3.0' as "target"
  
  columns 
    val varchar2(4000) path '.'
) tb
;

And you can even get the index of the token if you want:
select col1, val
from 
data d,
xmltable( 
  'for $i at $idx in (ora:tokenize($X,",")) where ($target = $i) return ($idx, $i)'
  passing col2 as "X", 'CD 3.0' as "target"
  
  columns 
    val varchar2(4000) path '.'
) tb
;

